# Why doesn't Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2010 work on Windows XP?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I have made a windows based c#/.net 4.0 application in vs2010 and used the latest crystal reports for it. Then i needed to install a cr runtime on client's pc to execute the reports. But that works only on windows seven perfectly. But when i run it on windows xp on client end, it gives errors exceptions like crystaldecisions.shared.sharedutils etc [image: error image]

I don't know whats wrong with it. The same error occurs if we don't install cr run time on windows 7 based client's pc but after installing it there, this is removed and works very nicely.

Comment: This looks like a 64 bit vs 32 bit problem. "BadImageFormatException" basically means you are trying to load a DLL that was compiled in a different "bitness" than your executable.

Comment: i installed 32 bit run time on xp, the problem should not be there, i have checked on windows seven on 32 bit pc as well, it works there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the solution, error was that i was installing client's profile .net framework 4, but crystal reports viewer does not work in client profile, so when i installed a standalone full version of .net framework on client's end, it worked. I downloaded it from
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=17718
So, if you have your application in .net 4 with crystal reports, you must install .net framework 4 full, instead of client profile on client's pc, otherwise it would give strange exceptions and you would not find any solution as i did not, see no body answered.

Thanks
Atif